# What does the '@' - sign mean in a http-request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, httprequest

I'm writing a backend using *express* and *node.js*. I recently implemented **JWT-token**-generation.

That token is sent to the client after receiving the correct credentials.

This token should be saved on the client-side so it can be used for further requests, to avoid transmitting the password in every request.

Problem: I don't have a client-side yet.
So I wonder, if/how I can even save this token at all?

---

To check my backend, my teacher gave me a list of CRUD requests for testing.

Test-request (a):

```
// Login with Basic Authentication as admin using correct Credentials admin:123
###
# @name loginAdminCorrect
GET http://localhost:999/authenticate
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz

@adminToken = {{loginAdminCorrect.response.headers.Authorization}}
```

My server will take this request, validate it and generate a Bearer Token.

The validation and token generation would also work without this @-part and I have no this part does:

```
@adminToken = {{loginAdminCorrect.response.headers.Authorization}}
```

---

Next, we should only allow some requests, when a valid token is sent within the request.

Test-request (b):

```
### List all Users with a Token of admin
http://localhost:999/users
Authorization: {{adminToken}}
```

So here it looks to me that we're using a Pseudo-Token instead of the actual token, which was generated before as a result of the test request (a).

**How can I test my code without the real/actual token, when my task is, to test the actual token-use-functionality?**

Also, I have not seen the '@' sign in HTTP-Requests before.

So why do I even have this part and what does it do?:

```
@adminToken = {{loginAdminCorrect.response.headers.Authorization}}
```

**What does this @-sign mean? And what does that whole line of code even do?**

---

Of course, I could just write code, that will always validate when I send a token called:
'Correct_Credentials_Token'. That would not be secure at all & useless. And then I would not even use the brackets '{{content}}'.

I don't see the point, but I guess it somehow makes sense, and I just don't get it.

Thank you guys, for answering this silly question!! Google didn't like the @-sign when I asked it I guess... :-/

---

bonus question:

```
# @name loginAdminCorrect
```

What does this mean and is this any important?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The `@` sign appears in the request body which is pretty much freeform as far as HTTP is concerned (i.e. it has absolutely nothing to do with HTTP). These all seem like questions best addressed to your teacher as they are about understanding what your task is and not about solving a programming problem.